# Xcode warning on validating and submitting app to App Store: Missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString

Tags: ios, xcode

After validating and submitting our iOS app, we saw a new warning related to the CFBundleVersionString. We never set this value before in Xcode and received the warning last night for the first time. Is setting this value a new suggestion from Apple?

After validation stage:

```
Missing plist key. The info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString
```

After distribution stage.

```
The submission succeeded. Some warnings were found during validation:

Warning ITMS-9000: Missing plist key. The info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString
```

Comment: Could you post your Info.plist file?

Comment: I'm also getting this all of a sudden. I didn't get the same warning when I submitted my last app (also "missing" this key, in that it's value is empty) on August 19, 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was made a warning (or maybe even mandatory?) on 8/20/2014 (or maybe 8/21/2014). I just made CFBundleShortVersionString the same as CFBundleVersion rather than risk a rejection.

Comment: Can you document your findings? Then you can get awarded the question. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it wasn't rejected after I made the CFBundleShortVersionString the same as the CFBundleVersion, but I have no idea if it would have been rejected without.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this isn't new (at least from as far back as remember, `CFBundleShortVersionString` has always been required). The `CFBundleShortVersionString` corresponds to the user-facing version string. You should add this key in your app's Info.plist file with the same value as the version you've specified as "Ready for Upload" in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

..**is missing the required key CFBundleShortVersionString  MISSING plist key**

I simply added it here in the Target General info> identity>

filling the the version number to be the same as the build number

Comment: Yes I think it might be since I submitted my app a few weeks ago without it without any error, (I then needed to make some changes) on resubmitting I then got the error so had to fill in the version number info - which was previously blank.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Bundle version in your project and version for release in AppStore not the same?